# Странное поведение контейнеров в GTK

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Недавно начал изучать gtk. Чтобы потренироваться начал писать небольшое приложение. Главное окно должно состоять из 3 колонн, где центральная должна забирать все свободное пространство, а боковые только столько, сколько им нужно. Я создал окно, добавил в него горизонтальный контейнер (GtkBox). С помощью функции gtk_box_pack_start() добавил 2 дочерних контейнера. Первый из них предназначен для поиска. И тут началось странное. Хотя я написал для первого параметры expand и fill оба FALSE, а для второго оба TRUE, но первый контейнер не занял крайнее левое положение, а разместился где-то на одной трети слева. Но дальше стало еще более странно, когда я изменил параметр fill левого контейнера на TRUE, то он занял крайнее левое положение (как я и хотел), но это прямо противоположно тому, что [говорится в документации](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBox.html#gtk-box-pack-start), ведь там написано про gtk_box_pack_start():

This parameter has no effect if expand is set to FALSE.

но у меня прямо противоположное поведение. Как решить эту проблему?

P.S. Я повторил структуру программы в glade. Проблема не ушла и всё выглядит также.

Вот сам код:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  GtkWidget * mainwin;          //GTK_WINDOW
  GtkWidget * box_content;          //GTK_BOX
  GtkWidget * search_for_note;          //GTK_SEARCH_BAR
  GtkWidget * search_entry;               //GTK_SEARCH_ENTRY
  GtkWidget * box_note;             //GTK_BOX

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  mainwin = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  box_content = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
  search_for_note = gtk_search_bar_new();
  search_entry = gtk_search_entry_new();
  box_note = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mainwin), 1280, 650);
  gtk_search_bar_set_search_mode(GTK_SEARCH_BAR(search_for_note), TRUE);
  gtk_widget_set_halign(search_for_note, GTK_ALIGN_START);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(mainwin), box_content);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_content), search_for_note, FALSE, FALSE, 0);  //тут проблема
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(search_for_note), search_entry);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_content), box_note, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  gtk_widget_show_all(mainwin);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Хотя я и устанавливал свойство expand как FALSE при добавлении в горизонтальный контейнер, но объект по прежнему расширялся, что и приводило к тому, что он находился на одной трети от левого края. Чтобы исправить это, нужно явно изменить его свойство hexpand на FALSE. Сделать это можно функцией
`gtk_widget_set_hexpand()`. А проверить, будет ли виджет расширяться или нет можно функцией `gtk_widget_compute_expand()`.

После добавления этой одной строчки проблема решилась.